# Create array with Set Extract in Cakephp with conditions

Tags: arrays, cakephp, set, extract

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [rate] => 82.50
            [pounds] => 2
            [ounces] => 3
            [mailtype] => Package
            [country] => UNITED KINGDOM (GREAT BRITAIN)
            [svccommitments] => 1 - 3 business days
            [svcdescription] => Global Express Guaranteed (GXG)
            [maxdimensions] => Max. length 46", width 35", height 46" and max. length plus girth combined 108"
            [maxweight] =>30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [rate] => 82.50
            [pounds] => 2
            [ounces] => 3
            [mailtype] => Package
            [country] => UNITED KINGDOM (GREAT BRITAIN)
            [svccommitments] => 1 - 3 business days
            [svcdescription] => Global Express Guaranteed Non-Document Rectangular
            [maxdimensions] => Max. length 46", width 35", height 46" and max. length plus girth combined 108"
            [maxweight] => 70
        )
```

And I want to use CakePHP's Set:extract tools to filter this array on the 'maxweight', so all elements that have a 'maxweight' more than X and get an array made up of the 'rate' and 'svcdescription' fields ie:

```
Array (
 [82.50] => Global Express Guaranteed Non-Document Rectangular
 ...
 etc
)
```

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, to get the most value out of `Set::extract`, it would be better to start with an array with a structure more like the following (otherwise I believe you'd have to run `Set::extract` inside a loop):

```
$array = array(
    'Shipping' => array(
        array (
            "id" => 4,
            "rate" => 82.50,
            "pounds" => 2,
            "ounces" => 3,
            "mailtype" => "Package",
            "country" => "UNITED KINGDOM (GREAT BRITAIN)",
            "svccommitments" => "1 - 3 business days",
            "svcdescription" => "Global Express Guaranteed (GXG)",
            "maxdimensions" => 'Max. length 46", width 35", height 46" and max. length plus girth combined 108"',
            "maxweight" => 30
        ),
        array (
            "id" => 6,
            "rate" => 82.50,
            "pounds" => 2,
            "ounces" => 3,
            "mailtype" => "Package",
            "country" => "UNITED KINGDOM (GREAT BRITAIN)",
            "svccommitments" => "1 - 3 business days",
            "svcdescription" => "Global Express Guaranteed Non-Document Rectangular",
            "maxdimensions" => 'Max. length 46", width 35", height 46" and max. length plus girth combined 108"',
            "maxweight" => 70
        )
    )
);
```

Now you can use the path syntax for `Set::extract()` to extract elements that have a maxweight greater than `$x`.

```
$extracted = Set::extract($array, '/Shipping[maxweight>'.$x.']');
```

With this data, you can build the array you're looking for using the rates as keys and svcdescription as values using `Set::combine()`.

```
$combined = Set::combine($extracted, '{n}.Shipping.rate', '{n}.Shipping.svcdescription');
```

Comment: `Set::extract` doesn't care about "preferred formats", it simply works on arrays.

Comment: its helpful though.. tnx a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this before, but thanks for encouraging me to read up on it.
Have you tried using Set::combine() ?

http://book.cakephp.org/view/662/combine

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use a foreach loop to process through the array.

```
$returnArray = array();

// Where $x is weight amount you're testing against
foreach ($yourData as $eachData) {
    if ($eachData['maxweight'] > $x) {
        $returnArray[$eachData['rate']] = $eachData['svcdescription'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously I could, I was just thinking it could be done a different way.

Comment: There are probably a lot of ways to do it. If I could offer advice, don't get caught trying to overoptimize or spend too much time trying to find the perfect tool when a good-enough tool will do....well.... good enough. :)